# Simple question about posets.

Tags: order-theory

Suppose that $X$ is a set, and $\geq$ is an ordering on that set. To determine if  $(X, \geq)$ is a poset, we must reflexivity, transitivity, and anti-symmetry. My question is concerned with this anti-symmetry part. That is, we must check that for each $a, b \in X$, $a \geq b$ and $b \geq a$ implies $a=b$. But isn't this dependent on how $=$ is defined? That is, isn't $=$ defined as $a=b$ if and only if $a \geq b$ and $b \geq a$ to begin with?

For example, what if we define an order $ \geq$ on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ by, $(a_{1}, a_{2}) \geq (b_{1}, b_{2})$ if and only if  $(a_{1}, a_{2})$ has SOME element larger than SOME element of $(b_{1}, b_{2})$. Then $(2, 1) \geq (1, 2)$ and $(1, 2) \geq (2, 1)$. Now, these elements are obviously not equal under the traditional pointwise ordering on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, but they could be seen as equal if we DEFINE equality as $(a_{1}, a_{2}) = (b_{1}, b_{2})$ iff $(a_{1}, a_{2}) \geq (b_{1}, b_{2})$ and $(b_{1}, b_{2}) \geq (a_{1}, a_{2})$? If so, it makes the entire exercise trivial, by why must we refer to some "traditional" ordering? Don't we DEFINE set equality in a way that makes anti-symmetry trivial?

Comment: Equality is a primitive symbol of set theory, as is $\in$.

Comment: The relation $\ge$ defined by "$(a_1,a_2)\ge(b_1,b_2)$ if and only if $(a_1,a_2)$ has SOME element larger than SOME element of $(b_1,b_2)$" is NOT an order because it's not transitive: $(0,2)\ge(1,4)$ and $(1,4)\ge(3,5)$ but $(0,2)\not\ge(3,5).$

Comment: Equality is not defined on base of some order. Intuitively $a=b$ means that the symbols "a" and "b" are labels for the same mathematical entity. In settheory $a=b$ means that $a\in x\iff b\in x$ is true for each set $x$.

Comment: drhab, the $a=b$ means that $a∈X$ and $b∈X$ is true for each set $X$ makes sense. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, including $X = \{a\}$ :)

Comment: Haha! But, no insanity ever started. Two things are equal iff they are one and the same thing. So if $a \in X \iff b \in X$ for *all* sets X, this includes $X = \{a\}$. Clearly, $a \in \{a\}$, so $b \in \{a\}$. $\{a\}$ has one element; so $b$ *is* that element, namely, $a$.

Comment: Are we then justified in saying that $2$ is not equal to $2/1$ because $2$ is not in $\{x \in \mathbb{R} |$ x written as a fraction$\}$ ?

Comment: *expressions written as fractions* are not real numbers, they're strings of symbols which (may) *denote* real numbers. (Re "may": not all expressions do denote reals, e.g. "1/0".) So, strictly speaking, the collection you define is the empty set: there are no strings of symbols in $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

No, $=$ is actual identity, not some notion of equivalence defined by $a \le b \wedge \le a$. The anti-symmetry condition says:if $a, b \in P$, $a \le b$ and $b \le a$ then $a$ really is the same entity as $b$.

An ordered set $\mathsf{P} = (P, \preceq)$ where $\preceq$ is only reflexive and transitive is called a *preorder*. For preorders, distinct elements $a, b \in P$ can bear the relation $\preceq$ to each other. In that case, the equivalence relation $a \equiv b \iff a \preceq b \wedge b \preceq a$ is nontrivial. If $\mathsf{P}$ is in fact a poset, the equivalence relation is just actual identity.

Equality *is* identity, it's a primitive in first-order logic, and does not get redefined. If the example you gave worked, you wouldn't be (re)defining **equality**, you'd be defining an equivalence relation.

Note that the relation you define is not even a preorder: it's *not* transitive. Instead of writing $\le$ which is misleading, let's write it as $R$. Then: $(0, 2) R (1, 0)$ and $(1, 0) R (-1, 1)$, but not $(0, 2) R (-1, 1)$.

Comment: But what does identity mean? I could say that $2$ is not the same "entity" as $2/1$, couldn't I?

Comment: No, you can't. The two different *expressions* you exhibit two both evaluate to one thing, the number $2$. Many different terms and expressions can denote the same thing -- "the morning star" and "the evening star" both are Venus.

Comment: So, are you suggesting that anti-symmetry is an exercise in checking identity, and not equality? So identity and equality are distinct things?

Comment: Identity and equality are the same thing, in common usage. See my remarks in the answer about those terms *vs* the broader notion of "equivalence".

Comment: I added a note about the example relation you give: it's not transitive.

Answer (score 0):

Equality (identity) is essentially defined by the property that $a=b$ implies $\Phi(a)\iff \Phi(b)$ for any predicate $\Phi$. That is, two objects are equal only if they are the same, indistinguishable.

Comment: How exactly are you defining your function above?

Comment: @Mark There was a typo. Clearer now?

Comment: Thank you very much, yes. I'm still trying to think of any possible gaps that still may exist in that definition... The best that I can come up with is, does 2=1+1? By your definition, the predicate could be, "described as the sum of two integers", so that 1+1 is, but 2 is not. What would be the resolution of this?